# Browser show incomplete JSP data

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts

I am using JSP, Struts 1.3 and Apache Tomcat 5.5.
For some reason response from JSP is being truncated and complete information is not shown. 
Class generated from the problem JSP page looks just fine.
There are no any errors logged in Catalina's logs.
I have no idea how this issue can be fixed.

**Update:** I'm sure that I'm looking in the right log for errors ($CATALINA_HOME/logs). Besides I'm writing some log messages to custom log file. There are no any mentions about this error in both of them. Error happens only in one specific page and content is truncated in the same place. If I print the same entity few times page output looks perfect. If I remove some outputs before this place the cut border is shifted: Memory allocation issues? Page buffer size doesn't effect on page output, I've checked. In this page I use include directive and I've met some information that if the size of generated servlet exceeds 64 KB, your JSP compilation will likely fail. Servlet generated just fine and I'm stuck.

Comment: Did you really look in the right place in the right logs for the errors? Without it, it's shooting in the dark. Further, it would be useful to know if this happened in a sudden or not and if this happens to all or specific pages only. Also, are those pages using the old fashioned and errorprone *scriptlets* or not?

Comment: Post the JSP code - there are a lot of reasons this can happen.  Also, there is an exception in one of your logs, you just haven't found it.

Comment: Here, `<%@page buffer="none"%>` helped to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per your update:

> If I remove some outputs before this place the cut border is shifted

It look like that something went wrong during closing the outputstream. I'd check the entire filter chain if there isn't some filter which replaces the `HttpServletResponse` with a custom implementation which in turn is poorly implemented, e.g. it doesn't properly delegate the `close()` method to the 'original' outputstream/writer. Try disabling the filter and retest it. Also try to add the following line to the *bottom* of the JSP to see if it fixes the problem:

```
<% response.getWriter().flush(); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the similar problem Where Only part of the JSP file is displayed(downloaded) in the Browser(Debugger/Pagesource). The worrying part was that it wasn't always happening.

I found that there was an `NullPointerException` being thrown because of a connection Timeout which ultimately was responsible for Sending only part of JSP back by the Server.

So, as advised in the comments by others, do look into your logs properly.